# Swift section header uilabels disappear when scrolling uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I am having a Grouped style UITableView, in which there are sections populated (no of items based on my REST data). Each section has a viewForHeaderInSection (a custom section header - XIB) and a cellForRowAtIndexPath. When I tap on my header, I am toggling to show/hide UILabels present in a UIView of the custom header.

At the same time I am also increasing the height of the row with the total height calculated after the section header is expanded.

All is working great so far, the only problem is when I scroll up an expanded section, all the UILabels (and the images inside the UIView of the header) are disappearing.

Am I missing something obvious?

I looked at many similar questions but with no positive clue. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149551/tableview-section-headers-disappear-swift), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421557/uitableview-section-header-views-disappear-when-scrolling), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771227/custom-uitableviewcells-disappearing-when-scrolling)

[This is what is happening](http://g.recordit.co/Q74cLLYWvG.gif)

***How is it different from my other question*** : The question that is assumed original of this question is different but used the same codebase. 
The original question was about calculating height of a row/sectionheader and this is about the cell being disappeared on the tableView.

Comment: Could you provide some of the codebase so it can become more clear what happens behind the scene?

Comment: @Dido: The codebase is huge, but I have the essentials already posted in a question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718598/swift-tableview-row-height-updates-only-after-scrolling-or-toggle-expand-colla

Comment: Got it, I am marking it as a duplicate then ;)

Comment: The question there was about heights of rows. But this is a different problem I believe. So I posted it as a new question.